# can not resolve data with firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, observable, google-cloud-firestore, angular-resolver

I have a firebase setup application and need to get all documents in a collection before the related component render.

Data is coming through a normal subscription

```
this.db.getCountryList().subscribe(countryList => this.countryList = countryList); //working, I have the country list now
```

But when I use a resolver like below, it does not resolve data or nothing happens.

```
@Injectable()
export class CountryListResolver implements Resolve<Country[]> {

  constructor(private db: DatabaseService) { }

  resolve(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.db.getCountryList();
  }

}
```

service

```
getCountryList(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.db.collection<Country>(this.countryPath,ref => ref.orderBy('name', 'asc')).valueChanges();
  }
```

routing

```
{ path: 'geo', component: GeographicalDataComponent, resolve: {countryList: CountryListResolver } },
```

component

```
this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
       this.countryList = data['countryList'];
});
```

and registered my resolver in the root module and other non-firebase resolvers are working fine.

Why is this setup resolver not working?

**version**

firebase:4.11.0

angularfire2:^5.0.0-rc.6.0

angular:^5.2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolver not returning Firestore's data to load a component in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518784/resolver-not-returning-firestores-data-to-load-a-component-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CHANGE:

```
return this.db.getCountryList();
```

TO:

```
const doc = this.db.getCountryList().toPromise();
return doc.then(data => {
    return data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As myself had troubles to get this, and maked such question as you did, I tryied somethings after perceive that the request is not endend by the resolver, so the keypoint to solve this is just to complete the request with a workaround pipe as I exposed in my question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64582997/3923628

Comment: Either mark it as a duplicate or copy the answer here as well?