# Resolver not returning Firestore's data to load a component in Angular

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, lazy-loading, angular-resolver

I'm trying to lazy load a component and I've following this Angular Guide ([Angular Guide: Preloading component data](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#preloading-component-data)), but I'm even don't getting data back from the resolver and so the component isn't being shown. Let's to my flat simple code:

**Service**

```
export class OrdersService {
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private http: HttpClient) {}

  getCoffeeOrders() {
    // return request = this.http.get('http://date.jsontest.com/'); // Works, but it's not the right data
    return this.firestore.collection<CoffeeOrder>('coffeeOrders').valueChanges();;
  }
}
```

**Resolver**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Resolve,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CoffeeOrder, OrdersService } from './shared/orders.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GetCoffeeOrdersResolverService implements Resolve<CoffeeOrder[]> {
  constructor(private ordersService: OrdersService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<CoffeeOrder[]> | any {
    console.log('GetCoffeeOrdersResolver');

    return this.ordersService.getCoffeeOrders();
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-order-list',
  templateUrl: './order-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order-list.component.css'],
})
export class OrderListComponent implements OnInit {
  coffeeOrders;
  res;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.route.data.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.res = res;
    })
  }
}
```

**Routing**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { GetCoffeeOrdersResolverService } from './get-coffee-orders-resolver.service';
import { OrderListComponent } from './order-list/order-list.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OrderListComponent,
    resolve: { orders: GetCoffeeOrdersResolverService },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**My structure version**

```
Angular CLI: 10.1.7
Angular: 10.1.6
Agular Fire: 6.0.3
rxjs: 6.6.3
typescript: 4.0.3
```

[This is my Gist with the files](https://gist.github.com/dixavier27/6e7eb89f4a61db8b40b82cfdeaeade6e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryied somethings after perceive that the request is not endend by the resolver, so the keypoint to solve this is just to complete the request with a workaround pipe in my resolver.

```
export class GetPatientsResolverService implements Resolve<Patient[]> {
  constructor(private patientService: PatientService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<Patient[]> {
    return this.patientService
      .getPatients()
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
      .pipe(take(1)); // HERE IS THE TRICK!
  }
}
```

The **take(1)** method at the pipe call terminate the requisition and after can wait for the answer bringing it to the resolver and service rightly.

**Why use take() instead first()?**

Basically:

- **take(n)** is not greedy, so will try that it will return the first n elements in the collection and if the collection is empty will not throw an error.
- **first()** is greedy, and ensures that it will return exactly one element or throw an error

Comment: But this does not give you real time update to the resolved data.